# React reducer question on changing a returned payload

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to either add a new field into a returned payload or add a new field copying the contents of another field in the returned payload object.  Here is my reducer code...

[actionTypes.GET_PAYTYPE_CONTRIBUTORS]: (state, action) => {
return {...state, paytypeContributors: { ...action.payload }, loadingPaytypeContributors: false, }
},

For each entry in action.payload.Items, I need to either change the field name ID to Id or add Id to the payload Items array with the same contents as the ID field has.

Here is where I tried to do this...

[actionTypes.GET_PAYTYPE_CONTRIBUTORS]: (state, action) => ({...state, paytypeContributors: { ...action.payload, Id: action.payload.Items.ID }, loadingPaytypeContributors: false}),

The payload returns an object and then Items inside of the object is an array and ID is a field in the array.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, that would be my take on this:

```js
const actionFunc = (state, action) => ({ ...state,
  paytypeContributors: { ...action.payload,
    Items: action.payload.Items.map(Item => {
      const newItem = { ...Item,
        Id: Item.ID
      };
      delete newItem['ID'];
      return newItem;
    })
  },
  loadingPaytypeContributors: false
});

const state = {};
const action = {
  payload: {
    Items: [{
        ID: 1
      },
      {
        ID: 2
      },
      {
        ID: 3
      },
      {
        ID: 4
      }
    ]
  }
}

console.log(actionFunc(state, action));
```